# Como solicitar permissão de administrador em Visual Basic.NET

Tags: vb.net

Estou criando um projeto que acessa pastas protegidas do Windows. Como faço para requisitar o acesso administrativo ao usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Se toda a aplicação necessitar de correr com privilégios elevados, não necessita de fazer alterações no código. Basta adicionar um manifesto que informa o Windows que a sua aplicação deve ser corrida com privilégios elevados.

Para isso:

1. Aceda as propriedades do projecto;
2. View Windows Settings;
3. Adicione a seguinte linha `requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`